# undefined reference on make_pair with static const

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

The following code gives an error on gcc 4.7 in my class.cpp :

```
  auto TLV1 = std::make_pair(UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST, Value1); 
  auto TLV2 = std::make_pair(UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST, Value2);
```

`UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST` is `static const unsigned char` defined in class, the Values are `vector<unsigned char>` define in function

EDIT : In my class.h :

```
static const unsigned char UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST = 0x4F;
```

The linker error :

```
 undefined reference to `foo::UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST'
 undefined reference to `foo::UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST'
```

The following code does NOT reproduce the error :

```
  unsigned char t = UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST;
  auto TLV1 = std::make_pair(t, Value1); 
  auto TLV2 = std::make_pair(t, Value2);
```

**EDIT :** 
I've made it works ok thanks to Neil Krik by casting :

```
auto TLV1 = std::make_pair(static_cast(UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST), Value1);
```

or Vlad solution, in cpp file :

```
const unsigned char foo::UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST= 0x4F
```

Comment: I don't know, this is why I'm asking ...

Comment: There is a problem in C++ where you have a static const in a class definition and try to use it with a function that takes a reference. This might be resolved in C++11 somehow, possibly using `constexpr`, I don't know. Try `std::make_pair((unsigned char)(UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST), Value1);`

Comment: What is the full line of code for the `UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST`  declaration?

Comment: The cast is working. 
@Niall I've edited with the line ...

Comment: @NeilKirk can you explain me why I need to cast ?

Comment: Because make_pair probably wants a reference, however unless you provide a definition for your static const outside the class (probably in a source file), it has no memory allocated to take a reference too. The cast just copies the value in a temporary local variable and passes that instead. It's just a quirk of C++.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reading, and answer, and don't only downvote me because you think I've forgot to defined my variable in my class

Comment: Here's some interesting related reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler requires that this static member would be defined. At present it is only declared within the class.

Include in some cpp module the following line

```
const unsigned char foo::UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST;
```

According to the C++ Standard

> 3 If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or
>   enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify
>   a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is
>   an assignmentexpression is a constant expression (5.19). A static data
>   member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with
>   the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is
>   an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In both
>   these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. —end note
>   ] The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is
>   odr-used (3.2) in the program and **the namespace scope definition
>   shall not contain an initializer**.

Comment: Thanks. It's working, so if I understand well, when I defined the following in my header file : `static const unsigned char UNSIGNEDCHAR_STATIC_CONST = 0x4F;` , there is no memory alocated, and I can't use is as a rvalue ?

Comment: @MoKaT The compiler can use it only if it need not its address. For example you could use this constant to define a size of an array. The compiler simply substitute it for the value at compile time. Static data members of a class are only declared within the class. They have to be defined if they are ODR-used (there is such a term in the C++ Standard).

Comment: @MoKaT See my updated post. There was a typo. If an initializer for a static const data member is specified in the declaration within the class then it shall not be specified in the definition of the data member.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I'll now intinialize my static const in my .cpp file, and it's working. Note that the other way (ugly way I think) of getting this works, is to cast it in the same type.

Comment: @MoKaT very often it is useful to initialize them in the class definition that the compiler can use their values at compile time inside the class definition.